# How can I place all symbols exported from a Python package at the package scope?

Tags: python, package

A couple of months ago, I happened to use BeautifulSoup in some Python project and I noticed the library was organized in a somewhat unique manner.

In order to use the BeautifulSoup class you only have to import the top-level package, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I knew that it was because the BeautifulSoup class, which is basically the only class provided by the library, is directly placed in `__init__.py` within the `bs4` directory with the clear intent to make importing the library simple.

I wondered if such practice is considered appropriate when I build my own library.

Obviously placing classes at the package scope by writing the class body in `__init__.py` will inflate the file indefinitely, but I do not either like the usual Python way in which there is usually only one class (or whatever unit of code) per module.

In short, I do not like to write redundant import statements like this, which seems inevitable when placing one class per module:

```
from mylibrary.splendidparser import splendidparser
from mylibrary.supremetimer import supremetimer
from mylibrary.superbrenderer import superbrenderer
```

And instead, I prefer the BeautifulSoup way:

```
from mylibrary import splendidparser
from mylibrary import supremetimer
from mylibrary import superbrenderer
```

Is there any way I can package my library to enable this importing style without inflating `__init__.py`?

Comment: If your class lives in a module other than the top level package's `__init__`, you need to either do the import in `__init__`, or have the user do it themselves. The import system has to know where to find the class somehow...

Comment: That being said, you can probably write a function based on distutils or something to automagically discover all your subpackages and submodules and import everything they export through `__all__`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Importing within `__init__` served my purpose. I was too dumb to come up with that solution... Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I just finally understood your question. Will provide an actual answer for you to select momentarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to put the implementation in `__init__.py`. You can put the definitions in other modules inside the package directory and then just import them in `__init__.py` and they will then be available from there.

Yes, this is appropriate. Try `import this` and you'll see the Zen of Python, which the community tries to follow, including "Flat is better than nested."